Is this IVP ill-posed?
I'm being asked to (i) use Euler's method in this question to approximate the solutions of an IVP, (ii) as well as to give its theoretical error bound. The IVP is defined as follows:
$y'=\frac{1+t}{1+y}$
where $1\le t \le 2$ given $y(1)=2$ and $h=0.5$
For the second part of the question (ii), I'm also given that solutions to the IVP is:
$y(t)=\sqrt{t^2+2t+6}-1$
Now, in the textbook I'm using, it says that Euler's method is used to obtain approximations of well-posed IVP's, where well-posed(ness) is determined by the continuity of the underlying function $f(t,y)$ where $(t,y)\in D=\{(t,y)|a\le t \le b,y\in \mathbb{R}\}$ (while also satisfying a Lipschitz condition on $D$). $y'$ (or $f$) is clearly a discontinuous function on $D$ (at $y=-1$), so this problem is ill-posed right?
Although it seems inappropriate, I can apply Euler's method on this IVP, obtaining approximations to the real solutions. However when it comes to determining the error bound, I fail to bound the derivative of $f$, given that it is not continuous at $y=-1$ (infinite discontinuity in both the function and the derivative function). Is there something I'm not understanding about this, because the textbook seems to have a solution for this regardless of the discontinuity?

Your solution is never near the discontinuity of $f$. Your textbook uses a definition that reduces the complexity of the existence proof, but it is not the last word. Can you pick a set $D'$ that is large enough to contain $(t,y(t))$ for interesting $t$ and bound $f$ there?

Nothing is better for testing a numerical scheme than an IVP that has an explicit solution. Euler has to be used with care but no one said it cannot be used when the IVP looks ill posed.

@Moo yes. Modifying the domain for y of the subset D allows for both Euler's method and the error bound to work as intended. For this example I limited y to being >=2
